# org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long Exception when trying to use MERGE INTO

Tags: apache-spark, apache-iceberg

Iceberg `MERGE INTO` is throwing a ClassCastException when data is stored in path partitioned by a numeric column like date (ex: /tmp/data/yyyymmdd=20220202).

Here's a minimal reproducible example.

```java
public class MRE {

    private static SparkConf getSparkConf() {
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
        sparkConf.set("spark.master", "local[*]");
        sparkConf.set("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions");

        // Catalog configs
        sparkConf.set("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://metastore-url:9083");
        sparkConf.set("spark.sql.catalog.hive", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog");
        sparkConf.set("spark.sql.catalog.hive.type", "hive");
        sparkConf.set("spark.sql.catalog.hive.uri", "thrift://metastore-url:9083");
        sparkConf.set("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "hive");
        sparkConf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog");
        sparkConf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.type", "hive");

        return sparkConf;
    }

    private static SparkSession getSparkSession(SparkConf conf) {
        return SparkSession
                .builder()
                .config(conf)
                .getOrCreate();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = getSparkSession(getSparkConf());

        Dataset<Row> df = spark
                .read()
                .option("basePath", "/tmp/data")
                .json("/tmp/data/yyyymmdd=20220202");

        String namespace = "temp";
        String tableName = "iceberg_test_table";

        System.out.println("Creating table and writing..");
        df.writeTo("hive." + namespace + "." + tableName)
                .tableProperty("location", "/tmp/iceberg/" + tableName)
                .tableProperty("write.format.default", "orc")
                .createOrReplace();

        System.out.println("Writing again using MERGE INTO");
        df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp_view");
        String mergeIntoQuery = "MERGE INTO hive." + namespace + "." + tableName + " AS table\n" +
                        "USING (SELECT * FROM tmp_view) AS updates\n" +
                        "ON table.keyA = updates.keyA\n" +
                        "WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET *\n" +
                        "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *";
        spark.sql(mergeIntoQuery);

        Dataset<Row> out = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM hive." + namespace + "." + tableName);
        out.show();
    }
}
```

The data file is just this

```json
{"keyA": "valueA", "keyB": "valueB"}
```

put inside `/tmp/data/yyyymmdd=20220202` folder.

Interestingly, the error disappears when we remove the `basePath` option from spark.read. The error also disappears when we comment out the `WHEN MATCHED` portion of the query.

```
Iceberg version: 1.2.1
Spark version: 3.3.0
Scala version: 2.12
```

EDIT: df.schema and output of `describe table` as requested.

```
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- keyA: string (nullable = true)
 |-- keyB: string (nullable = true)
 |-- yyyymmdd: integer (nullable = true)

df.show()
+------+------+--------+
|  keyA|  keyB|yyyymmdd|
+------+------+--------+
|valueA|valueB|20220202|
+------+------+--------+

spark.sql("describe tmp_view").show()
+--------+---------+-------+
|col_name|data_type|comment|
+--------+---------+-------+
|    keyA|   string|   null|
|    keyB|   string|   null|
|yyyymmdd|      int|   null|
+--------+---------+-------+
```

```
describe table hive.temp.iceberg_test_table;
--------------------------------------
+---------------+---------+-------+
|col_name       |data_type|comment|
+---------------+---------+-------+
|keyA           |string   |       |
|keyB           |string   |       |
|yyyymmdd       |int      |       |
|               |         |       |
|# Partitioning |         |       |
|Not partitioned|         |       |
+---------------+---------+-------+

show create table hive.temp.iceberg_test_table;
-----------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE hive.temp.iceberg_test_table (
    keyA STRING,
    keyB STRING,
    yyyymmdd INT
)
USING iceberg
LOCATION '/tmp/iceberg/iceberg_test_table'
TBLPROPERTIES (
    'current-snapshot-id' = '6802515410364264173',
    'format' = 'iceberg/orc',
    'format-version' = '1',
    'write.format.default' = 'orc'
)
```

Full error stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3) (192.168.1.7 executor driver): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToLong(BoxesRunTime.java:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BaseGenericInternalRow.getLong(rows.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BaseGenericInternalRow.getLong$(rows.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericInternalRow.getLong(rows.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.JoinedRow.getLong(JoinedRow.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.writeFields_0_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.addMetadataColumnsIfNeeded(FileScanRDD.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.next(FileScanRDD.scala:204)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToLong(BoxesRunTime.java:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BaseGenericInternalRow.getLong(rows.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BaseGenericInternalRow.getLong$(rows.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericInternalRow.getLong(rows.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.JoinedRow.getLong(JoinedRow.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.writeFields_0_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.addMetadataColumnsIfNeeded(FileScanRDD.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.next(FileScanRDD.scala:204)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a comment from OP, which is might be the answer.

> *There is a similar open issue in iceberg repo https://github.com/apache/iceberg/issues/8333, maybe it is a bug –
> Harshith Bolar*

---

```
            .option("basePath", "/tmp/")
```

should be

```
            .option("basePath", "/tmp/data")
```

---

I assume you have a column named `yyyymmdd` in `iceberg_test_table`. If you still have problems, please update the OP with output of `df.schema` and `describe table iceberg_test_table`.

---

[From docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#partition-discovery)

> *Starting from Spark 1.6.0, partition discovery only finds partitions under the given paths by default. For the above example, if users pass `path/to/table/gender=male` to either `SparkSession.read.parquet` or `SparkSession.read.load`, gender will not be considered as a partitioning column. If users need to specify the base path that partition discovery should start with, they can set `basePath` in the data source options. For example, when `path/to/table/gender=male` is the path of the data and users set `basePath` to `path/to/table/`, gender will be a partitioning column.*

Comment: Added /tmp/data to basePath, issue still persists, question edited and updated.

Comment: @HarshithBolar can you also add output of `df.show()` ?

Comment: Also I don't think it's a problem, but your table should've been partitioned by `yyyymmdd` I guess?

Comment: Added df.show(). No I am not partitioning my output table. Just tried partitioning it by yyyymmdd, the error still exists.

Comment: Few last things before I give up. 0. Include the actual error message/stack-trace. 1. Use a non-keyword for alias, e.g. `" AS t1\n"` instead of `" AS table\n"` in the MERGE statement. 2. Add output of `spark.sql('describe tmp_view').show()` (that's python, convert to scala if needed). 3. Can you start from scratch, use some new target table name (ensure it's empty), new source folder, new temp_view name (in case some meta data is cached somewhere). All in all, I see no reason for the error given schemas and actual data.

Comment: Thanks Kashyap. I have added the full stacktrace and the output of describe tmp_view. I also tried using aliases t1 and u1 but the error still exists. There is a similar open issue in iceberg repo https://github.com/apache/iceberg/issues/8333, maybe it is a bug

Comment: Also I don't think this is a schema issue. If I read from a folder named `/tmp/data/yyyymmdd_20220202` with everything remaining the same, it works perfectly. The issue seems to be with reading data from partitioned folders

Comment: Yes, I would say it's very likely something specific to iceberg. But how is this not a critical bug that everyone is facing? Seems like a bread-n-butter usecase. To prove it you can repeat the whole thing using stock hive catalog/metastore (or delta if you're into it) instead of iceberg catalog and tables, if it works then it's an iceberg problem.